# What are more common alternatives to "unexpelable"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word that means "to not to be able to expel".

Example sentence:

> I have a fish bone in my throat. I couldn't get it out. The thing was
>   __

Comment: Consider *stuck*.

Comment: _Unexpellable_ is perfectly understandable as a word, but it would not be used to describe a fish bone stuck in your throat. It would be a usable word to describe some rich high school kid whose father had paid for half the new school wing, and whom the school would therefore be all but unable to expel even if he behaved in a way that would surely get any other student expelled. That student would be _unexpellable_.

Answer (score 2):

You can say the fish bone is *[stuck](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/stick)* (*fixed in a particular position or unable to move or be moved* [Oxford]) in your throat.

You can also say it is *[unremovable](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/unremovable)* (*unable to be removed* [Oxford]).

Answer (score 1):

"*Unremovable*" would do, provided that it's an acceptable word - I'd swear I've seen it and heard it countless times but my best dictionary seems to ignore it.

Comment: Unremovable or irremovable?

Comment: To me "_irremovable_" would denote a state of mind, sort of "_adamant_", whereas "_unremovable_" would rather suggest a physical condition. Just a personal point of view, of course.

Answer (score 1):

You could say the fishbone was *lodged* in your throat. Indeed, consider The Cambridge Online Dictionary's blurb: Lodge
 to become fixed or cause something to become fixed in a place or position:
[ I ] A fish bone had lodged in her throat.

Answer (score 1):

The closest I can think of (especially to the example context) is ***inextricable***.

> I have a fish bone in my throat. I couldn't get it out. The thing was
>   ***inextricable***.

vocabulary.com:

> **[inextricable](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/inextricable)**
>   **1**
>   *adj* **not permitting extrication**; incapable of being disentangled or untied
>
> **[extrication](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/extrication)**
>   **1**
>   *n* the act of releasing from a snarled or tangled condition